# Python Gui button command executing without button push. Only passing function and have tried Lambda

Tags: python, tkinter

The command for my button on my secondary window is executing as soon as the primary window is opened. I have seen other related answers and am only passing the function object. I have also tried Lambda even though I'm not passing any arguments. New to GUIs. Appreciate the help. Code below:

```
import tkinter
from src.accounting import runpayroll


class TopGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.geometry('300x250+500+200')

        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.labelspace = tkinter.Label(self.frame, text='')
        self.label = tkinter.Label(self.frame, text='What would you like to do?')
        self.labelspace2 = tkinter.Label(self.frame, text='')

        self.process_payroll_button = tkinter.Button(self.frame, width='25', bg='white', text='Process payroll', command=self.process_payroll_gui)

        self.frame.pack()
        self.labelspace.pack()
        self.label.pack()
        self.labelspace2.pack()
        self.process_payroll_button.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def process_payroll_gui(self):
        self.additional_window = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.additional_window.geometry('300x250+500+200')

        self.run_payroll_button = tkinter.Button(self.additional_window, width='25', bg='white', text='Run payroll', command=runpayroll.run_payroll)
        self.run_payroll_button.pack()
        self.run_payroll_button.place(x=60, y=80)

topgui = TopGUI()
```

Comment: When I run the above code (after mocking out `run_payroll`, it does _not_  immediately execute the command associated with the button, and I see nothing in the code that could cause that. I get an attribute error, but that's a different problem than the one you're asking about.

Comment: what version of python are you running...doesn't happen on 3.4 when i tested....are you sure you're showing us all your code?

Comment: There are five more non-functioning buttons and their pack statements that I cut out to make it easier to read. I'm running 3.5

Comment: The only notes I'm getting from PyCharm are that the additional window and the run_payroll_button are being defined outside of __init__

Comment: Your question is unclear. You specifically asking about a function that is automatically running, but your code doesn't exhibit that behavior. Is this a general "why isn't this code working" question (ie: do you need help with other problems not asked in the question)? Those sorts of questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: It's very specific. The code works. It just works twice in my environment. Once on opening the main GUI and again when I push the run_payroll_button.

Comment: If I comment out the import statement and put a dummy run_payroll function in, it works. Is there something the import statement could do to make that happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an execution statement at the bottom of the file I was importing that was used for debugging that module. It was executing right away. I only found it thanks to those who said it worked fine without the import statement.